# React-Router not rendering array content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, router

I'm following an article from Medium about using React Router to create a SPA; but is not up to date, so some things has changed.

I'm stuck in rendering an array of products; but for some reason it is not recognizing any content.

Code:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Widgets from './components/Widgets';
import Wudgets from './components/Wudgets';

const widgetprods=[
  {name: 'Master Widget', price:'$125.00'},
  {name: 'Sub Widget', price:'$115.00'},
  {name: 'Long Widget', price:'$150.00'},
  {name: 'Short Widget', price:'$135.00'}
]

const wudgetprods=[
  {name: 'Master Wudget', price:'$75.00'},
  {name: 'Sub Wudget', price:'$85.00'},
  {name: 'Long Wudget', price:'$135.00'},
  {name: 'Short Wudget', price:'$110.00'}
]

const App=()=>{
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className='App'>
        <Navbar />
          <div className='container'>
              <Routes>             
                <Route exact path='/' element={<Home/>} 
                /> 
                <Route exact path='/widgets'
                       render={(props) =>
                         <Fragment>
                            <Widgets prods={widgetprods}/>
                         </Fragment>
                       }
                />
                <Route exact path='/wudgets' 
                       render={(props)=>
                         <Fragment>
                            <Wudgets prods={wudgetprods}/>
                         </Fragment>
                       }
                />
              </Routes>
          </div>   
      </div>
      </Router>
  )};
  
export default App;
```

**--->** I see this:
[image]

**--->** I spect to see this:
[image]

**--->** One of the erros I get:
[image]

Thanks a lot!!

Luc

Comment: why use render: () => <Fragment><Wudgets prods={wudgetprods} /></Fragment> instead of element={<Wudgets prods={wudgetprods} />} ?

Comment: Hi @JiaSH ! 

Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly! 
I've tried to do something similar, but I did not write the sentence properly I guess...

In anycase, I had used render=() because I was following a tutorial from Medium, but it is out of date, and using render function was justified as the author of the article quotes: "_We tell it the path to the Component but since we want to pass props, the widgetprods Array, we use render. This allows us to specify the Component, Widgets, as well as the props_"

Merci!